# Why does my node.js app crash when visited in the browser if mongodb authentication is enabled?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, authentication, mongoose

I'm in the process of deploying my first node.js application. The full stack is MERN based, and I'm attempting to get it running on an aws lightsail instance. I built the application as two separate repos, a backend with views that can look at and interact with a database and a frontend built in react that's a game.

I have node.js and mongoDB correctly installed on my instance and I'm able to run the application through the instance just fine. I know because by visiting the public ip with the port included and authentication is off I'm able to access the backend app as expected. Viewing, posting, editing, deleting entries in the db.

When I enable mongodb's authentication the node app starts fine on the server but as soon as I navigate to the application within a browser it crashes the node.js application on the server. I get this error message. (I have gone through the steps of creating an admin and db specific user for mongod through mongosh)

```
/home/ec2-user/server/node_modules/mongodb/src/cmap/connection.ts:440
          callback(new MongoServerError(document));
                   ^
MongoServerError: command aggregate requires authentication
at Connection.onMessage (/home/ec2-user/server/node_modules/mongodb/src/cmap/connection.ts:440:20)
    at MessageStream.<anonymous> (/home/ec2-user/server/node_modules/mongodb/src/cmap/connection.ts:267:56)
    at MessageStream.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at MessageStream.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at processIncomingData (/home/ec2-user/server/node_modules/mongodb/src/cmap/message_stream.ts:168:12)
    at MessageStream._write (/home/ec2-user/server/node_modules/mongodb/src/cmap/message_stream.ts:65:5)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:389:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:330:10)
    at MessageStream.Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:334:10)
    at Socket.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:754:22) {
  ok: 0,
  code: 13,
  codeName: 'Unauthorized',
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}
```

I have setup the uri connecting to mongodb through mongoose with the correct user name and password, which I'm sure of because I have a console.log that prints out that the DB connection was successful.

Example uri:

```
'mongodb://username:userpass@pri.vate.ip:27017/DBname?authSource=DBname&w=1
```

Connection code

```
if(dbConnection) {
    mongoose.connect(dbConnection, {
        useNewUrlParser: true
    } as ConnectOptions,
        err => {
            if (!err) {
                console.log('DB connection successful')
            } else {
                console.log('Error in DB connection ', err)
            }
    })
}
```

My backend application has a password protection that is completely separate from mongodb using express-basic-auth, but I'd like the extra layer of security since that's the recommended by mongoDB docs.
I believe that it's crashing because it is expecting the client to somehow provide db credentials but I have no idea and could really use some help understanding what the issue is.

**Tech notes:**
Aws Lightsail running amazon linux 2 
node.js local: v16.14.2 server: v16.15.0
mongoDB v5 community edition
mongoose v6.3.1

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57848302/how-to-solve-command-find-requires-authentication-using-node-js-and-mongoose) might help.

Comment: Thanks for posting! I read that thread and have done the steps in the accepted answer. I have both admin and app specific users within mongosh. The error does seem similar! However if I understood that question correctly their application was failing when running the app was started on the server. Which mine does just fine. It's once I open a browser and try to visit my application that it crashes it on the server. I haven't had any issues auth'ing on mongosh or accessing the db through compass or initial connection through my application. Thanks for your consideration.